# How to compare $\left(1+|y|^k\right)^2$ and $\left(1+|y|^2\right)^k$ for $y\in\mathbb{R}^d$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

When comparing different characterizations of the Sobolev space $H^k$ (e.g. Evans's Partial Differential Equations and Folland's Real Analysis), I end with the following question:

> Show that there exist constants $C$ and $D$, depending only on $d$ and $k$, such that for all $y\in\mathbb{R}^d$
>   $$
> C\left(1+|y|^2\right)^k\leq\left(1+|y|^k\right)^2\leq D\left(1+|y|^2\right)^k\tag{*}
> $$
>   where $|\cdot|$ is the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

One way to do it is using the binomial theorem and handling the middle terms by considering separately $|y|<1$ and $|y|\geq 1$. Could anyone come up with an alternative (maybe more efficient) way to get (*)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the quotient. For $k > 0$,

$$f \colon y \mapsto \frac{(1 + \lvert y\rvert^k)^2}{(1 + \lvert y\rvert^2)^k}$$

is a strictly positive continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^d$ with

$$\lim_{\lvert y\rvert \to \infty} f(y) = 1.$$

Thus it follows that $f$ is bounded and bounded away from $0$, i.e. there are $0 < C < D$ with

$$C \leqslant f(y) \leqslant D$$

for all $y \in \mathbb{R}^d$.

The case $k = 0$ is clear, and the case $k < 0$ is handled by multiplying numerator and denominator with $\lvert y\rvert^{2\lvert k\rvert}$.

Comment: This is very elegant and neat! I have never seen any book  does such a estimate when introducing the space $H^k$. This could be generalized to compare $\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k}|y^\alpha|^2$ (where multi-index is involved) and the two terms in the title. This saves times!