# Easy proof for an estimate

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

For a proof involving Fourier transforms I need the following estimate: For a given $y \in \mathbb R^d$ there exists an $c > 0$ with
$$\frac{1}{1 + \vert x - y \vert^2} \leq c \frac{1}{1 + \vert x\vert^2} \qquad 
 \text{for all } x \in \mathbb R^d.$$
$\vert \cdot \vert$ denotes the euclidean distance. I have a rough idea that you can choose a great enough $c$, because $\frac{1}{1 + \vert x - y \vert^2}$ is bounded on $\mathbb R^d$ and you just need to make sure that $c \frac{1}{1 + \vert x\vert^2}$ doesn't decay too quickly to majorize the other function. But I really struggle to establish this estimate formally. I would appreciate some hints on the topic or an easy proof if you know one :)

Comment: [Not the same question, but the analogous idea works.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1955002/how-to-compare-left1yk-right2-and-left1y2-rightk-for-y-in-m)

Comment: @DanielFischer Define $f(x) = \frac{1 + \vert x\vert^2}{1 + \vert x - y \vert^2}$. Then $f$ is strictly positive and continuous and $\lim_{\vert x \vert \to \infty} f(x) = 1$. Hence $f$ is bounded. Like this?

Comment: Yes. So there are constants $0 < a < c$ with $a \leqslant f(x) \leqslant c$ for all $x$.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I just need $c$ though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you don't need an optimal constant:
$$1+|x|^2=1+|y+(x-y)|^2\le1+|y+(x-y)|^2+|y-(x-y)|^2=1+2|y|^2+2|x-y|^2<2(1+|y|^2)(1+|x-y|^2),$$ so $c=2(1+|y|^2)$ would turn the trick. It's a bit rough, but the proof is easy, as you wanted it.